# なぜrcxをpushする必要があるのか？

Tags: x86, gdb

アセンブラを独学中です。大学で情報をやっているわけでもないのであまり専門用語を使う際は簡単な説明を入れてもらえると助かります。

Hello, worldを10回表示させるプログラムを書きましたが
rcxをsyscallの前後でスタックから出し入れする必要がありました。これはなぜでしょうか？

```
global _main
section .text
_main:
    mov rcx, 10

loop_label:
    mov     rax, 0x2000004
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, msg.len

    push rcx       ; to avoid register rcx from changing
    syscall
    pop rcx        ; to avoid register rcx from changing

    ; inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 10
    loop loop_label

    mov     rax, 0x2000001
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall


section .data
msg:    db      "Hello, world!", 10
.len:   equ     $ - msg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

短い答え
Linux の `syscall` の仕様で `rcx` は `syscall` の前後で保存されないからです。

長い答え
[The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/)

Linux の 64bit ユーザーソフトウエア (Ring3) が Linux Kernel (Ring0) を呼び出す目的で `syscall` 命令を発行するときの仕様が解説されています。引数の渡し方、結果の受け取り方、レジスタ保存則などなど。で、ここの説明によると `syscall` から戻った時 `rcx` と `r11` の値は壊されてしまうとあります。あなたのプログラムは `rcx` の値が変わってしまうとうまく動かない構造になっているので `push`/`pop` が必要なわけです。

Comment: 非常に正確かつ明瞭な回答をありがとうございます！