# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "printf" ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64

Tags: x86

[nasmで1~100まで数える - Qiita](https://qiita.com/akakou/items/fb42e0dbfe9e5dc0a588)

上記の記事を参考に次のコードを実行しますとエラーが返されました。調べたところオプションを設定する必要があるとかないとかのようですがよくわかりません、よろしくお願いします

```
extern printf                  ; printf関数を持ってくる

section .data
    fmt: db "iteration: %d", 10, 0         ; printfで用いるフォーマット

section .text
    global _main
_main:
    mov rdx, 1                  ; 初期値
    mov rcx, 10

_loop:
    push rcx                  ; rcxの避難
    push rdx                  ; rdxの避難

    mov rdi, fmt                ; フォーマット
    mov rsi, rdx                ; カウントしている値

    call printf               ; printfをコール
    ; printfのコール時にレジスタの値が消えてしまう

    pop rdx                  ; rdxを持ってくる
    pop rcx                  ; rcxを持ってくる

    add rdx, 1               ; rdxに１加算

    cmp rcx, 0
    loop _loop                  ; ループバック

fin:
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

エラー

```
 $ ld -macosx_version_min 10.14 -lSystem -o p100 p100.o
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
     "printf", referenced from:
          _loop in p100.o
      ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

また、

```
mov rsi, rdx
```

としている理由がわかりません

Comment: 記事の前回相当分（ [nasmでprintf関数を使う - Qiita](https://qiita.com/akakou/items/b3279b2de09b62261b7e) ）は正常に実行できましたか？

Comment: いえ、書き換えましたがダメでした。

Comment: エラーの出力部分で `ld` を使っているようですが、なぜでしょうか？（記事では `nasm` を利用しているようですが……）

Comment: ちなみに、手元の環境では記事の内容を正常に実行できました。

Comment: 調べてみるとgccだと無理でしたmacだからです。

Comment: macはframeworkで多くの標準ライブラリを管理してます。`-lSystem`ではなく`-framework System`なら行くのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined symbols` の原因は `ld` が `libSystem.dynlib` を見つけることに失敗しているんだと思います（憶測：間違っている可能性大）。要するに `ld` に対するオプション `-L` が足らないんでしょう。オイラんとこには Mac 無いので具体的にどうすればよいかはわかりません。

`mov rsi, rdx` が必要なのは `x86-64` Application Binary Interface (ABI) 仕様がそのように求めているからです。詳しく説明すると本１冊になっちゃうので
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions
の System V AMD64 ABI あたりから参照のこと。

あなたのプログラムは `rcx` と `rdx` をレジスタ変数として使っているのですが ABI 仕様により、関数 (この例では `printf`) を呼び出す際の引数に `rcx` や `rdx` を使うことが定められているので、提示のように `push` / `pop` が必要となります。

と、言いたいところなんですが

提示プログラムは `x86-64 ABI` のレジスタ保存規則ならびにスタック仕様を満たしていないので正しく動きません。今動いているとしたら偶然です（障害が顕在化してないだけ）。
[なぜrcxをpushする必要があるのか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54768/)
でもレジスタ保存規則、スタック仕様を満たしていないので、動いているのは偶然です（指摘しようかなと思ったけど本筋でないので略したっす）。

現代 `ABI` はコンパイラを使う前提で設計されていて、アセンブラを手書きすることはほとんど全く想定されていません。関数は（この例では `main` が）その入口と出口で決められた仕様を満たすコードを必ず実装しなければならないことになっています。コンパイラなら忘れずに実装できますが、アセンブラ手書きだととても面倒。この辺の規約ならびに CPU の仕様を熟知した人間でないとアセンブラ手書きは実装コストに合いません。

本職でないのなら `x86-64` アセンブラの手書きを覚えるなどまったくもって遠回りで、学習コストのみ高くついて、でも得られるものが少ないです。オイラの後輩君がアセンブラ手書きを覚えたいと言ったなら一度は止めさせます（既にそれなりの知識があってかつ興味もあるのであれば GO させるでしょうが）本当にその必要があるのかどうかゆっくり検討してみてください。

Comment: んーありがとうございます。私自身独学で色々調べ調べでやってきました。目的としてはセキュリティについて知って例えばmetasploitなどのフレームワークをただ使うのではなく、自分でコーディングするレベルに行きたいと思っています。この場合何を勉強すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 脆弱性の発生機序の発見方法とか、その対応策の策定とかしたいってことだと終局的にはやはりアセンブラレベルの知識が必要なんですが、今の x86 (32bit/64bit) はある意味究極に難しい CPU となってしまっていて、学習コスト的にものすごく高価につきそうです。実務であるなら x64 アセンブラ手書きなどお勧めしないのですが、趣味の範囲ならモチベーションが続く限りにおいてはチャレンジしてみるのも良い、んではないですかね。脆弱性のネタ元のソフトはほぼ間違いなく高級言語で書かれている（直接アセンブラで書かれてはいないはず）ので、オイラならコンパイラの吐き出すアセンブラがなぜこうなっているかを学ぶのを優先します。手書きアセンブラはそのあとでも遅くないかと。

Comment: なるほど、詳細にありがとうございます。できればそんおコンパイラあたりでいい教材を教えてもらえないでしょうか？出来るだけ簡単なものから始めたいのですがもし少しレベルの高いものであってもそれを読むための補助教材も教えていただけると非常に助かります。

Comment: それはこの質問の主題とは離れた別の話題なので、別スレッドを挙げていただくほうが良いと思います。コメント欄でサゲ進行するよりよほど有意義なQ&Aになりそうなネタですよね。

Comment: かしこまりました。そちらの方でよろしくお願いします